# Multilinear extension of submodular function

Tags: multilinear-algebra, set-valued-analysis

I am reading the [wikipedia article about submodular functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submodular_set_function#Definition).
Let $\Omega$ be a finite set and $f\colon 2^\Omega\to \Bbb R$ a submodular set function, i.e. a function such that
$$f(S)+f(T)\geq f(S\cup T)+f(S\cap T) \qquad \forall S,T\subset \Omega$$
Note that there are other equivalent characterizations in the article.
Now, the article talks about a multilinear extension $F\colon [0,1]^{|\Omega|}\to \Bbb R$ of $f$ ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submodular_set_function#Multilinear_extension)) defined by
$$F(x)=\sum_{S\subset \Omega}f(S)\prod_{i\in S}x_i\prod_{i\notin S}(1-x_i).$$

> How is $F$ multilinear and how to check it?

I tried to build an example for $\Omega = \{1,2,3\}$ and the budget additive function $f(S)=\min\{3,\sum_{\tilde s\in S}\tilde s\}$ (e.g. $f(\{1,2\})=\min\{3,1+2\}$). I get $F(x,y,z)=x+2y+3z-xz-2yz$ and don't see any way how could $F$ be [multilinear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilinear_form).

Comment: I don't think "multilinear" is being used here in the sense that you (or I for that matter) would normally use it. Since the $x$ variables are restricted to $[0, 1], F$ is not even defined on a vector space. I think it is just a name used to label this particular extension, for other reasons I am not aware of.

Comment: It is multilinear. Every summand is linear in $x_i$, holding all other coordinates constant.